# Inject Blade Array into script using HTML data attribute

Tags: php, html, laravel-blade

I have a blade template, which has a script included in it. That script needs access to language strings, which are accessible in a `@lang('intro')` variable. I am wondering if there is way of injecting the whole array into the script via a html data attribute, and then retrieve it in the script using jquery.

So far I have the following:

../en/intro.php:

```
<?php
return [
    'step1' => 'Welcome',
    'step2' => 'Step 2',
];
```

../de/intro.php

```
<?php
return [
    'step1' => 'Willkommen',
    'step2' => 'Schritt 2',
];
```

In the blade template I am injecting each string:

```
<script data-id="intro-script" 
        data-introStep1="@lang('intro.step1')" 
        data-introStep2="@lang('intro.step2')" 
        src="{{ mix('js/intro.js') }}">
```

And retrieve it using jQuery in the script `intro.js`:

```
document.querySelector('script[data-id="intro-script"]').getAttribute('data-introStep1');
```

This works so far, but isn't great for many more strings. I am wondering if its possible to combine `data-introStep1` and `data-introStep2` in a single data attribute which contains the whole `@lang('intro')` array, not just a single string per attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation file can be packed as JSON encoded string like so:

```
<script data-id="intro-script" 
    data-intro='@json(__('intro'))'
    src="{{ mix('js/intro.js') }}"
></script>
```

Then, retrieve using Javascript.

```
const intro = JSON.parse(
  document.querySelector('script[data-id="intro-script"]').dataset.intro
);
```